# Find most used id int comma seperated string in Mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I have a Mysql database with a column that stores ids in a comma seperated string. I now need a Mysql command that gives me the most used id in all rows.

For example this Column

- id_12,id_13,id_14
- id_12,id_15,id_13
- id_11,id_12,id_18

Now i need a query that gives me the most used ids. In this case the most used is id_12 with 3 and the second most used is id_13 with 2.

I hope its understandable what i need

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related with [this one] ([Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)).

I do think that your task is bound to be awkward and inefficient if you store the values in a comma-separated list. It would be far easier if you stored id values one per row. Then you could do this:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But just telling you "you're doing it wrong, change everything" doesn't answer the question you asked.

The best I can come up with given your comma-separated list format is:

First create another table that has each id value, one per row.

```
create table idvalues ( id char(4) primary key );
insert into idvalues values ('id_11'),('id_12'),('id_13'),('id_14'),('id_15'),('id_18');
```

Then you can join this to your table and use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to match each value to the lists:

```
SELECT idvalues.id
FROM idvalues JOIN yourtable 
  ON FIND_IN_SET(idvalues.id, yourtable.id_list);
```

This will produce a result set that you can count, as if you had stored the data in normal form:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT idvalues.id
    FROM idvalues JOIN yourtable 
      ON FIND_IN_SET(idvalues.id, yourtable.id_list)
) AS t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But the caveat is that FIND_IN_SET() cannot be optimized with an index, so it's bound to do a Cartesian product. In other words, it will have to use that function as many times as the number of rows in `idvalues` multiplied by the number of rows in `yourtable`. It'll take a long time if these tables are large.

If you want this kind of query to be better optimized, then avoid using comma-separated lists.

Comment: Is it an ideological position?